php mailer sending and receiving from same email
I have php code that sends feedback form data to specific email(receiver). The setFrom() function receives email(sender) from html form. But the email is send with email(receiver).
HTML
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
    <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required><br><br>
    <label for="email">Your Email:</label><br>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required><br><br>
    <label for="subject">Subject:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" required><br><br>
    <label for="message">Message:</label><br>
    <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="4" cols="50" required></textarea><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="send">
</form>

PHP
<?php


   use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

   use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;


    require 'phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
    require 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
    require 'phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';





if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST["send"])) {

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    try {
        
                       
        $mail->isSMTP();                                         
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                 
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                                   
        $mail->Username = 'RECEIVER@gmail.com';                    
        $mail->Password = 'SECRET';                         
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
      
        $mail->Port = 465;                                 

        //Recipients
        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom($email, $name);

        $mail->addAddress("RECEIVER@gmail.com", );
     

       
        //Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = $_POST["subject"];
        $mail->Body = "Name: $name\nEmail: $email\n\nMessage:\n$message";
        //$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

        $mail->send();
        echo "Send Successfully!";

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    }

}


The setFrom() function receives email(sender) from html form...why? You don't have the permission or ability to send an email on that email account's behalf, from their account. That would be impersonation. If the mailserver doesn't outright reject your initial attempt (which I think Gmail would anyway), then at the very least any servers the message is sent onwards to would spot the mismatch between the sender address and the domain of the originating mailserver, and blacklist it as a spam / spoofing attempt. It's unclear why you've even attempted this approach?

If you want to capture the email address of the person completing the HTML form, just put that into the message body of the email, and/or the Reply-To header (if you want to be able to reply directly to that person from the receiving account)

Take a look at the contact form example provided with PHPMailer that explains how you should do this.
